Wightman distribution is complex Lorentz invariant
I asked in Math.SE (here), but I have not gotten answer, so I ask in Phys.SE.
How do I prove that Wightman distribution's analytic continuation is invariant under complex proper Lorentz transformation $L(\mathbb{C}^{D})$?
Properties are given in followings.

Domain is an open set in $(\mathbb{C}^D)^{N-1}$.

Invariant under real proper Lorentz transformation. That is, $w_N(\zeta_1,...,\zeta_{N-1})=w_N(\Lambda\zeta_1,...,\Lambda\zeta_{N-1})$ for all $\Lambda$ in real proper Lorentz group for $\mathbb{R}^D$.

For a neighborhood $U$ of $id_{\mathbb{C}^D} \in L(\mathbb{C})$(complex proper Lorentz group) , $U \to \mathbb{C}, \Lambda\mapsto w_N(\Lambda\zeta_1,...,\Lambda\zeta_{N-1})$ is holomorphic.


This invariance is asserted in my textbook by Schottenloher. (You can read here for free at RG.)

Do you have any idea to prove?

Edit
I came up a way.
A new holomorphic function $w'_N$ can be defined as $w'_N(\Lambda \zeta_1,...,\Lambda\zeta_{N-1})=w_N(\zeta_1,...,\zeta_{N-1})$ for $\Lambda \in U$ : open neighborhood of $id_{\mathbb{C}}$. $w'_N$ is probably analytic continuation of $w_N$
, and the uniqueness of analytic continuation means $w'_N=w_N$ then $w_N \circ \Lambda=w_N$ for $\Lambda \in L(\mathbb{C}
)$.
Am I on right way?

I haven't the time to answer now, but a note: on faster stacks like Overflow, Mathematics, etc. it can often take a second to get a good answer, but you frequently do get one eventually.

Thanks for comment. Alright. I hope you will be back when you have time.
